# How to save a complete webpage and load later for offline in DroidGap

Tags: android, caching, cordova

i want to make aplication that can save or load data cache when ofline in phonegap, but it doesnt work this is my code,
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
//super.loadUrl("http://192.168.43.190/TA/index.php");
//WebView webView = new WebView( context );
super.appView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 5 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 5MB
super.appView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
super.appView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
super.appView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
super.appView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
super.appView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT ); // load online by default

if (!isNetworkAvailable() ) { // loading offline
super.appView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
}

super.loadUrl( "http://192.168.43.190/TA/index.php" );
}
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService( CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}
}
```

do anyone can help me...? thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Phonegap, and I can't tell what your exact problem is (Crashing? Nothing showing up? Formatting strangely?), but try

```
setContentView(webView);
```

if you want a new WebView to popup after loading the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Store your data into the shared preference if you want your application to work offline.